# Asking a question with a known answer

Tags: discussion

Earlier today, I was about to submit a new question regarding layout XML. Before submitting, I had a simple thought that I figured I'd try, and it ended up working.

I was hesitant to then ask the question followed by including an answer immediately. I know others could benefit, so I do believe it's a worthwhile question, but I'm not sure if this type of "quick tips" type of posting would be a good candidate for a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that Robert's comment *only* applies during this very early phase of the site, for the reasons that he mentions.  If you're asking whether this is allowed in general, I think the answer is yes, it is not only allowed, *it's encouraged*:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

In my opinion, any non-trivial question and answer add value to a stackexchange site.

Note that not everyone is aware of this, and you will many times be downvoted for answering your own question - particularly if you do it quickly - by people who aren't aware of this.

Comment: Good to know. +1

Answer (score 2):

Please be careful about *staging* questions you already know the answer to… ***especially* so early in a site's development.** I try and convey this to every new site we launch, but your home page says a lot about your site. If there's a sense that that the users don't really need the help they are asking for, **the whole exercise would likely be perceived as a waste of time.**

Please, at least read

[**Your New Site: Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)

I understand that you actually had the question you asked about. But let's not present this as some type of solution — to start adding "quick tips" as a way of growing this site. Ask about problems you actually have, and please don't *"seed"* questions as a way of upping your numbers.

It will not work. Trust me.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to just ask the question and leave it to be answered for X amount of time before providing a solution? Not to "game" the system in any way, but it's something I've been curious about in the past with SO.

Comment: @pspahn In my opinion, that's a pretty risky proposition. The folks here are **real people** taking their valuable time out to help you. If they learn you never needed the help in the first place, you are betraying an essential motivation for folks who take the time out to share their hard-earned knowledge through this site.

Comment: Very good point. I didn't like the idea myself, but hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to ask a question and answer it right away.

If you think your finding can be useful to others, consider writing a blog post. In case you don't have your own blog you can contribute to any existing Magento related blog. I'm sure they will be glad to publish it.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" checkbox (on the bottom of the page where you write/ask your question) for a reason.

It's appreciated if you share knowledge Q&A style as long as it's not a silly mistake. If it's actually something that could help many others then please do share!

Comment: I agree. If you already were about to click the submit button for your question, in my opinion it would be a pity to just throw everything away. By marking your answer as a community wiki answer, it wouldn't look like you just want to gather reputation because you don't get reputation for the answer (right?) but you still can help other people having the same question.